# SQL improvement - UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables: "packages" and "items".

"`packages`" has the following columns: `pack_id | item_id`

"`items`" has the following columns.......:    `item_id | type`

One **package** can have *multiple* **items**.

**UPDATE:**

Sample Data and Expected Results:

```
pack_id | item_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           2
2           1
3           4
3           5
3           6

item_id | type
1           C
2           F
3           Z
4           Z
5           Z
6           Z
```

Expected result:

```
pack_id | pack_type
1           Mixed
2           Cool
3           Not Cool
```

My question is:

Is there a better way to query these 2 tables, in order to get a 3rd one, having as columns: "pack_id" and the new column "pack_type"? Those UNIONs seem to add a huge amount of time to the run time.

```
    SELECT pack_id, pack_type
    FROM (    
      -- CASE 1 - pack_type is 'Cool' - type 'C' or 'F', but not 'Z'        
      SELECT  Distinct q1.pack_id, 'Cool' AS pack_type    
        FROM (
            SELECT  Distinct p.pack_id, i.type
            FROM packages p 
            INNER JOIN items i
                ON p.item_id = i.item_id
            WHERE i.type <> 'Z') q1
        WHERE q1.type IN ('C','F')

      UNION        

      -- CASE 2 - pack_type is 'Not-Cool' - type 'Z', but not 'C' or 'F'
      SELECT  Distinct q2.pack_id, 'Not-Cool' AS pack_type    
        FROM (
            SELECT  Distinct p.pack_id, i.type
            FROM packages p 
            INNER JOIN items i
                ON p.item_id = i.item_id
            WHERE i.type = 'Z') q2
        WHERE q2.type NOT IN ('C','F')

      UNION

     -- CASE 3 - pack_type is 'Mixed' - type 'Z' and ('C' or 'F')
     SELECT  Distinct q3.pack_id, 'Mixed' AS pack_type    
        FROM (
            SELECT  Distinct p.pack_id, i.type
            FROM packages p 
            INNER JOIN items i
                ON p.item_id = i.item_id
            WHERE i.type = 'Z') q3
        WHERE q3.type IN ('C','F')
    ) m
```

NOTE: some explication for the multiple comments that point to "A type cannot be Z and also C or F".

I also thought that, but the way I understand the behavior of the query is that if u say "type IN ('C','F')", it will look at each item of type 'C' or 'F' and get the package id that has that item. BUT, a package that has items of type 'C' or 'F' can also have items of type 'Z', hence the inner select, dealing with items of type 'Z' first.

Comment: UNION is a bit slower than UNION ALL because it has to check for duplicates. But you should be able to do this entire thing in a single query with some case expressions.

Comment: @Sean.. I was just typing that to suggest `CASE` based on the `Type`.

Comment: You can also store a procedure that puts results of selects into temp table. In the end return that tamp table ;)

Comment: Your predicates seem a bit strange to me. Looking just at the first query you basically said get me the rows where i.type <> 'Z' AND i.type in ('C', 'F') What is the point of <> 'Z'? Any value of C or F is already NOT Z. I think something is missing in your example because this just doesn't make much sense to me and it seems way over complicated.

Comment: You don't need both Distinct and Union (use Distinct&Union all or Union only)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the original query, but how can `q1.type` in the 2nd and 3rd query reference the first query?

Comment: @WEI_DBA should be q2 and q3

Comment: That's what I thought, but then the inner query would only return `type = 'Z'` for 2nd and 3rd queries

Comment: @WEI_DBA Otherwise you get syntaxis error. But things are worst. The last query doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @adlisval You should provide some sample data and explain what result you expect. Right now your query doesnt make sense and have some sintaxis errors.

Comment: There's a good chance that this query isn't doing exactly what you want it to do. Assuming a package has one or many items, it looks like you want to categorize the entire package based on the presence or absence of a particular item type. It may be easier for us to help you if you post some very simple sample data with an example of your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your observations. I corrected the query, changing q2 and q3 instead of q1, for the 2nd and 3rd query. @SeanLange Please se the note in the question. Hopefully will explain why it needs i.type <> 'Z' AND i.type in ('C', 'F')

Comment: But any given row that is redundant. If the type is either C or F it already can't be Z since it can't have more than 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when isnt explain on the question I guess your package type is derived from the combination of items on it. So you need group the items on each package

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/CAKQ32399)**

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT pack_id, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN i.type IN ('C','F') THEN 1 END) as total_CF,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN i.type = 'Z' THEN 1 END) as total_Z
     FROM packages p 
     INNER JOIN items i 
        ON p.item_id = i.item_id
     GROUP BY pack_id 
)
SELECT pack_id, 
       CASE WHEN total_CF > 0 and total_Z = 0 THEN 'Cool'
            WHEN total_CF = 0 and total_Z > 0 THEN 'Not Cool'
            WHEN total_CF > 0 and total_Z > 0 THEN 'Mixed'                
         -- ELSE 'NOT determinated'
       END as type
FROM cte
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Determining the package type was/is explained in the query's comments. Please see the note I added to the question. It's explaining why the suggested solution is not giving the right results.

Comment: My query produce your exact desire output. Please check the demo

Comment: Omg, it's true. I have to understand its logic, but it's also very fast (50min vs 4min). Thanks very much. I see you're not using "DISTINCT". I can't see any duplicates, but just to make sure, it's not needed here?

Comment: Nope, you are solving that with `GROUP BY`  and `COUNT` btw 4 min is still a lot you need create one index for `package (item.id)` and a composite for index for `item (item_id, type)`.

Comment: Actually I found some duplicates, so I used DISTINCT in the second select. (Please let me know if that's wrong)

Comment: Thanks for the indexes suggestion.

Comment: Without data I wouldn't know. But based on the logic you present you shouldn't need it. You can update the sql demo with the sample causing the duplicated and I can check later.

Comment: I will correct my self, dont need composite index ... only index for `item_id` should be enough but of course you can ask in a different question to help improve performace with the `explain plan`. Because unless you have millions of records 4 min is too much

Answer (score 5):

Maybe i have misunderstood something, but isn't this what you actually want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pack_id, 
    pack_type = CASE WHEN i.type IN ('C','F') THEN 'Cool'
                     WHEN i.type IN ('Z') THEN 'Not-Cool'
                     ELSE 'Mixed' END
FROM  packages p INNER JOIN items i ON p.item_id = i.item_id
```

There are three types: cool or not cool and everything else and you don't want a filter(just unique).

Comment: I think you are right .`type 'C' or 'F', but not 'Z'` is just `type IN ('C' or 'F')`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: yes, and also this doesn't make a sense(`Mixed` subquery): `type = 'Z' ... AND type IN ('C','F')`. A type cannot be Z and also C or F

Comment: Agree with @TimSchmelter. I was just saying that... :-)

Comment: I think we understand wrong this request. A package is a combination of items. So a `GROUP BY` is required somewhere. That is how you can have mix packages.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: maybe, but then informations are missing.

Comment: Wouldnt be the first time :(

Comment: Sorry for late comment. I updated the question with a note. In short, the query above does not give the right results. Please see the note.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put it in single query like this

```
SELECT  Distinct * 
FROM (
SELECT  p.pack_id,
        CASE WHEN i.type <> 'Z' AND i.type IN ('C','F') THEN 'Cool'
             WHEN i.type = 'Z' AND i.type NOT IN ('C','F') THEN 'Not-Cool'
             WHEN i.type = 'Z' AND i.type IN ('C','F') THEN 'Mixed'
        END AS pack_type
FROM packages p 
INNER JOIN items i ON p.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE (i.type <> 'Z' AND i.type IN ('C','F'))
    OR (i.type = 'Z' AND i.type NOT IN ('C','F'))
    OR (i.type = 'Z' AND i.type IN ('C','F'))
) as temp
```

**Updated:** After reviewed carefully your logic, I think @Tim answer is the right one

Comment: I think you can simplify Where condition to `WHERE i.type IN ('C','F') OR (i.type = 'Z' )`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Wouldn't `i.type IN ('C','F','Z')` be the same as what you have?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think Tim got it too

Comment: You made the same logical mistake as OP: `WHEN i.type = 'Z' AND i.type IN ('C','F')`